# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.StopWatch

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

when I run the code that [linear support vector machines svms](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#linear-support-vector-machines-svms), and cause the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/StopWatch
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:314)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.StopWatch
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Can you tell me the maven dependency that contains `org.apache.hadoop.util.StopWatch`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```